# What is the umask 'relative to'?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, umask

I understand that the umask is a 'last stage filter' that ensures specific permission bits are set off on newly created files or directories.  My question is, *what does it operate on?  How is the input permission set determined?*

To illustrate my confusion, consider this:

- I set the umask to 000
- I create a directory inside my home directory and the perimssions are 777
- I create a directory in the system root (/) with the help of sudo, and the permissions are 755

Why the difference?

Comment: It filter from the full set of permissions, so from `0777`

Comment: You shouldn't have permissions to create a directory under /, did you do that step as a different user, e.g. using sudo ? Or in a different shell ?

Comment: What are you using to create a directory? The mkdir command? Were you `root` in each of the two cases you mentioned?

Comment: I used sudo to create the directory in root.  I updated the OP to reflect this.

Comment: Did you run the umask command before the sudo, after the sudo but before the mkdir, or both?

Comment: Mark, it shouldn't be that hard.  What is the umask relative to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The umask is interpreted by certain system calls that create filesystem objects. It is typically relative to an explicit mode argument passed to the system call. For example, [mkdir](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/mkdir.html) works like this:

> ```
> int mkdir(const char *path, mode_t mode);
> ```
>
> The file permission bits of the new directory shall be initialized from `mode`. These file permission bits of the mode argument shall be modified by the process' file creation mask.

And [open](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/open.html) does this:

> ```
> int open(const char *path, int oflag, ... );
> ```
>
> the access permission bits (see <sys/stat.h>) of the file mode shall be set to the value of the *third argument* taken as type `mode_t` modified as follows: a bitwise AND is performed on the file-mode bits and the corresponding bits in the complement of the process' file mode creation mask. Thus, all bits in the file mode whose corresponding bit in the file mode creation mask is set are cleared.

A process's umask is inherited by its children, but of course any process can change its own umask.

Based on the information the OP has supplied, I will assume that the OP is running the following commands from a shell:

```
umask 000
mkdir ~/foo
sudo mkdir /foo
```

The [mkdir](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/utilities/mkdir.html) command uses a default mode as follows:

> The value of the bitwise-inclusive OR of S_IRWXU, S_IRWXG, and S_IRWXO is used as the mode argument.

So `S_IRWXU|S_IRWXG|S_IRWXO` is 0777, and as expected, with a umask of 000, the mode of `~/foo` will be 0777.

But [sudo](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/sudo.8.html) always sets a umask, either to the value listed in `/etc/sudoers` or a default chosen at compile time, which on Ubuntu is 022. So `sudo mkdir /root/foo` will run with a umask of 022, resulting a directory that is 0755.

Comment: Thanks Mark, it's more involved that I thought